# How to use variable data after Ajax Call Success - Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I created a small file manager to manage my files. On the one hand, the folder structure is shown thanks to JsTree. On the right I would like that based on the click on the left folder I was shown the files contained in that folder.
At the click an Ajax call is made which calls the selectFiles method to go through the routes. Now in the console i see the correct data, but i don't know how to use it into foreach in the blade.

**AJAX:**

```
// chiamata Ajax per selezionare files in base all'id
$('#treeview').on("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
    var id = data.node.id;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'archivio_documenti/+id+/selectFiles',
        data: {id:id},
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('Succes!',data);
        },
        error : function(err) {
            console.log('Error!', err);
        },
    });
});
```

**DocumentiController.php:**

```
/**
 * Selzionare files in base all'id della cartella
 */
public function selectFiles(Request $request){
    try{
        $id = $request->id;
        $files = \App\Documento::where('cartella_id',$id)->get();

        return response()->json(compact('files'));

    }
    catch(\Exception $e){
        echo json_encode($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

**Route:**

```
Route::post('archivio_documenti/{id}/selectFiles', 'DocumentiController@selectFiles');
```

**Update:**

```
                    @foreach($files as $key => $file)
                        <div id="myDIV" class="file-box">
                            <div class="file">

                                {!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE','route' => ['documento.destroy', $file->id]]) !!}
                                <button type="submit" class="#" style="background: none; border: none; color: red;">
                                    <i class='fa fa-trash' aria-hidden='true'></i>
                                </button>
                                {!! Form::close() !!}

                                <a href="/documento/{{ $file->id }}/edit" class="#" role="button" style="text-align: center;"><i class='fa fa-edit' aria-hidden='true'></i></a>

                                <input id="myInput_{{$key}}" type="text" value="{{'project.dev/'.$file->path.'/'.$file->file}}">
                                <a href="#"><i class="btnFiles fa fa-files-o" aria-hidden="true" data-id="{{$key}}"></i></a>

                                <a href="{{' http://project.dev/'.$file->path.'/'.$file->file}}">
                                    <span class="corner"></span>

                                    <div class="icon">
                                        <i class="img-responsive fa fa-{{$file->tipo_file}}" style="color:{{$file->color_file}}"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="file-name">
                                        {{$file->file}}
                                        <br>
                                        <small>Update: {{$file->updated_at}}</small>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    @endforeach
```

Comment: That's a javascript response, so you'll need to manipulate DOM to add your results to the view. jQuery has methods - like `append()` or `prepend()` that can help you with that.

Comment: @lesssugar it's possibile to send directly the files variable into blade?
I have @foreach() that use variable $files.

Comment: Show us your `foreach`, please.

Comment: @lesssugar i update my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, the `foreach` of yours is a bit complex, but the idea itself is simple: recreate the `foreach` loop from your Blade in Javascript and append the result to the DOM.

In your `success` callback you could e.g. do this:

```
$('#treeview').on("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
    var id = data.node.id;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'archivio_documenti/+id+/selectFiles',
        data: {id:id},
        success: function(data) {

            // Build the HTML based on the files data

            var html = '';

            $.each(data, function(i, file) {
                html += '<div class="file" id="file_' + file.id + '">' + file.updated_at + '</div>';
            });

            // Append the built HTML to a DOM element of your choice

            $('#myFilesContainer').empty().append(html);

        },
        error : function(err) {
            console.log('Error!', err);
        },
    });
});
```

Obviously, this is simplified and you'd need to use the HTML structure you've shown us in the `foreach` loop above, but the idea is the same: (1) loop through your files in the `data` object and build the HTML structure row by row, (2) put the whole HTML block in the DOM, wherever you need it to be displayed after the user clicked on a folder.

**Alternative:**

If you'd like to keep the `foreach` loop in Blade instead of of Javascipt, you could move the loop to a separate blade:

**folder_contents.blade.php**

```
@foreach($files as $key => $file)
                        <div id="myDIV" class="file-box">
                            <div class="file">

                                {!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE','route' => ['documento.destroy', $file->id]]) !!}
                                <button type="submit" class="#" style="background: none; border: none; color: red;">
                                    <i class='fa fa-trash' aria-hidden='true'></i>
                                </button>
                                {!! Form::close() !!}

                                <a href="/documento/{{ $file->id }}/edit" class="#" role="button" style="text-align: center;"><i class='fa fa-edit' aria-hidden='true'></i></a>

                                <input id="myInput_{{$key}}" type="text" value="{{'project.dev/'.$file->path.'/'.$file->file}}">
                                <a href="#"><i class="btnFiles fa fa-files-o" aria-hidden="true" data-id="{{$key}}"></i></a>

                                <a href="{{' http://project.dev/'.$file->path.'/'.$file->file}}">
                                    <span class="corner"></span>

                                    <div class="icon">
                                        <i class="img-responsive fa fa-{{$file->tipo_file}}" style="color:{{$file->color_file}}"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="file-name">
                                        {{$file->file}}
                                        <br>
                                        <small>Update: {{$file->updated_at}}</small>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    @endforeach
```

Then, in your controller:

```
public function selectFiles(Request $request){
    try{
        $id = $request->id;
        $files = \App\Documento::where('cartella_id',$id)->get();

        // Save the view as string
        $view = view('folder_contents.blade.php', compact('files')))->render();

        // Pass the ready HTML back to Javasctipt
        return response()->json(compact('view'));

    }
    catch(\Exception $e){
        echo json_encode($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you must set header for ajax

```
headers: {
        'X_CSRF_TOKEN':'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'Content-Type':'application/json'
    },
```

and in Controller

```
public function selectFiles(Request $request){
    try{

        $id = $request->id;

        $files = \App\Documento::where('cartella_id',$id)->get();

        return response()->json($files);

    }
    catch(\Exception $e){
        echo json_encode($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read the question properly this is not the right answer.